# Memory related issue with Strings in java network program

Tags: java, string, memory, network-programming

I am working on a small java network program for instant messages using sockets. In the application the messages are read using the `DataOutputStream's` `readUTF()` method, which return a `String object`. So every time a new message is arrived or sent a new String object is created in the memory, which in turn consumes memory. After a long time of communication there are several String objects in the memory.

So is there any way I can avoid this or I should try some other way of recieving messages. I am very new to Java network programming and its concepts.
Thanks. 
I have a very bad coding style still I will try to make the question clear.

```
String recievedMessage = dataInputStream.readUTF();
String messageType = recievedMessage.substring(0, recievedMessage.indexOf("##"));
String message = recievedMessage.substring(recievedMessage.indexOf("##") + 2, recievedMessage.indexOf("$$"));
```

After this the message object is inserted in a `JTextPane` using a `StyledDocument`.

Comment: Might be a good idea if you post a minimal example of your code

Comment: It depends on what your are doing with your `String` objects. When not referenced anymore, they are garbage collected.
+1 for a  minimal snippet.

Comment: Do you observe any issues with 'long time of communication there are several String objects in the memory', e.g. increased memory consumption or even an OutOfMemoryError? Or is it just a guess?

Comment: @home: I am using a profiling tool in netbeans ide. It shows a large number of objects in the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not specific to network programming: creating transient strings costs virtually nothing and they are efficiently garbage-collected. The only point where you'd start having issues would be if you retained the entire conversation transcripts in RAM. If you do need to save the transcripts, just forward all the messages to a file, without RAM retention.

Comment: I am saving (actually inserting) the strings in a StyledDocument object which is inseted in a JTextPane(previous contents are also kept). So I guess it will be stored in RAM.

Comment: Are you seeing any increased heap usage of your client program over a period of time ???

Comment: Obviously, you won't be able to avoid paying the memory cost of the text you are showing in the GUI. You must limit the amout of retained chat history and delete the oldest entries. However, don't start worrying about it until you experience actual problems. A person would have to be both very chatty and have great stamina in order to produce enough typed text to actually make a dent in JVM's typical heap size.

Answer (score 0):

what type of network is it, e.g. connect oriented or connection less? Do you have any memory issue? But I believe when packets are sent from point-to-point, it will consume some memory according to message type and after that it should be marked for garbage collection. It would be good if you mention what exactly do you have the issue.